# How to call multiple functions having different arguments using single button ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to call two different functions using a single button. I know we can do this by combining them but functions have different types of arguments.

Here is my code:

```
protected void ValidateCaptcha(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    ......

}



 protected void submit(object sender, System.EventArgs e)    {

    .....  }
```

HTML Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="submit"       ValidationGroup="submit" />
```

Comment: Do you use those methods for something else? if they are just for this purpose you could change the signature of `ValidateCaptcha` and call it from `submit` method...

Comment: I'm using submit method to insert some data in database and ValidateCaptcha will be used for validating captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Sender is same for both. You can make a function that gets arguments for both of them and call them with each one's arguments. Have you considered which arguments do you need for each? since eventargs are standard and most functions don't really need them maybe you can just call the functions

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. There is no need to call ValidateCaptcha explicitly because it will be called by customvalidator.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please mark your answer as solution to help other users with the same problem.